# Merge sort Linked List giving Segmentation fault

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am trying to sort a linked list using the merge sort. I have created 2 methods, one for dividing the Linked List and one for merging the divided list, but it is giving Segmentation Fault. Below is the code for sorting and merging. I am unable to find where my code is getting a segmentation fault. Please help. Thanks.

```
       struct Node *merge(struct Node *first,struct Node *second)
{
    struct Node *temp;
    if(first==NULL)
    return second;
    if(second==NULL)
    return first;
    struct Node *head;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        if(first->data<=second->data)
        {
            temp=first;
            first=first->next;
        }
        else
        {
            temp=second;
            second=second->next;
        }
        head=temp;
    }
    
    while(first!=NULL && second!=NULL)
    {
        if(first->data<=second->data)
        {
            temp->next=first;
            temp=first;
            first=first->next;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next=second;
            temp=second;
            second=second->next;
        }
    }
    
   if(first!=NULL)
    {
        temp->next=first;
    }
    
    if(second!=NULL)
    {
        temp->next=second;
    }
    
    return head;
} 

Node* mergeSort(Node* head) {
    // your code here
   if(head==NULL || head->next==NULL)
   return head;
   struct Node *fptr, *sptr;
   sptr=head;
   fptr=head->next;
   while(fptr && fptr->next!=NULL)
   {
           sptr=sptr->next;
           fptr = fptr->next->next;
   }
   
   struct Node *mid = sptr;
   printf("%d is mid\n",mid->data);
   struct Node* mid_next = sptr->next;
   mid->next=NULL;
   
   struct Node *first = mergeSort(head);
   struct Node *second = mergeSort(mid_next);
   
    struct Node *list= merge(first,second);
    return list;
    
}
```

Comment: You are reading head before it is set (if head==NULL)

Comment: Thanks @jmq . I set the head as NULL after declaring it. It worked.

Comment: Better yet, just remove the if (head==NULL) statement.  You don't need it.

Comment: I tend to like putting dummy head nodes in my linked lists, even if I need to synthesize one on the spot.  It often facilitates writing cleaner code, because then the first real data node is not a special case, and empty lists have a more satisfying representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding:

```
struct Node *head;     
if(head==NULL)
```

the pointer head has not been set to any known value. So comparing it to NULL is undefined behavior.

Please examine [mergesort for linked list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-for-merge-sort-for-linked-lists/0) where the key functions are listed below:

```
/* Link list node */
struct Node { 
    int data; 
    struct Node* next; 
}; 
  
/* function prototypes */
struct Node* SortedMerge(struct Node* a, struct Node* b); 
void FrontBackSplit(struct Node* source, 
                    struct Node** frontRef, struct Node** backRef); 
  
/* sorts the linked list by changing next pointers (not data) */
void MergeSort(struct Node** headRef) 
{ 
    struct Node* head = *headRef; 
    struct Node* a; 
    struct Node* b; 
  
    /* Base case -- length 0 or 1 */
    if ((head == NULL) || (head->next == NULL)) { 
        return; 
    } 
  
    /* Split head into 'a' and 'b' sublists */
    FrontBackSplit(head, &a, &b); 
  
    /* Recursively sort the sublists */
    MergeSort(&a); 
    MergeSort(&b); 
  
    /* answer = merge the two sorted lists together */
    *headRef = SortedMerge(a, b); 
} 
  
/* See https:// www.geeksforgeeks.org/?p=3622 for details of this  
function */
struct Node* SortedMerge(struct Node* a, struct Node* b) 
{ 
    struct Node* result = NULL; 
  
    /* Base cases */
    if (a == NULL) 
        return (b); 
    else if (b == NULL) 
        return (a); 
  
    /* Pick either a or b, and recur */
    if (a->data <= b->data) { 
        result = a; 
        result->next = SortedMerge(a->next, b); 
    } 
    else { 
        result = b; 
        result->next = SortedMerge(a, b->next); 
    } 
    return (result); 
} 
  
/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/* Split the nodes of the given list into front and back halves, 
    and return the two lists using the reference parameters. 
    If the length is odd, the extra node should go in the front list. 
    Uses the fast/slow pointer strategy. */
void FrontBackSplit(struct Node* source, 
                    struct Node** frontRef, struct Node** backRef) 
{ 
    struct Node* fast; 
    struct Node* slow; 
    slow = source; 
    fast = source->next; 
  
    /* Advance 'fast' two nodes, and advance 'slow' one node */
    while (fast != NULL) { 
        fast = fast->next; 
        if (fast != NULL) { 
            slow = slow->next; 
            fast = fast->next; 
        } 
    } 
  
    /* 'slow' is before the midpoint in the list, so split it in two 
    at that point. */
    *frontRef = source; 
    *backRef = slow->next; 
    slow->next = NULL; 
}
```